# Rails Active Scaffold : values of column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

```
  active_scaffold :mail_template do |config|
    config.list.columns = [:name, :language_id, :autocall_traitment_type]
    config.list.sorting = {:language_id => 'ASC'}
    config.list.sorting = {:autocall_traitment_type => 'ASC'}
    config.list.sorting = {:name => 'ASC'}

    config.show.columns = [:name, :subject, :language_id, :autocall_traitment_type, :body]
    config.update.columns = [:name, :subject, :language_id, :autocall_traitment_type, :body]
    config.create.columns = [:name, :subject, :language_id, :autocall_traitment_type, :body]
    # Other config options would be here
    config.columns[:language_id].label = "Language"
    config.columns[:language_id].form_ui = :select
    config.columns[:language_id].options = Language.find(:all).map {|l| [l.name, l.id]}
```

With this code, i have name of language in my screen:

[image]
but not here:

[image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 'Mail Templates' section is showing `language_id` instead of the `language.name`.

Add a helper method to the MailTemplate model.

```rb
class MailTemplate
  def language_name
    language.name
  end
end
```

Then change your scaffold list.columns `language_id` to `language_name`.

Comment: Happy new year. Fine if i add also belongs_to :language in model. I don't understand why is not work in helpers